# Send mail to each array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $emails. The `print_r($emails)` output following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => mail_1@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => mail_2@gmail.com
        )
)
```

Now I want to send emails to all email addresses in this array. I tried:

```
foreach($emails as $contact) {

$to      =  $contact;
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

What I get is: `Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: `$contact['user_email']`

Comment: You have an array of arrays.  So each element in that array is an array.  The error message is pretty clear, `mail()` doesn't expect an array.

Comment: You should also check for an empty email, like in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($emails as $contact) {

$to      =  $contact['user_email'];
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```